# R web scraping function getPageNumber error

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I  am building a webscraper and trying to understand why my getPage Number Function does not work. The function worked last night and tonight I have been having  an error getting the right output

```
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)

    getPageNumber <- function(URL) {
      parsedDocument <- read_html(URL)
      results_per_page <- length(parsedDocument %>% html_nodes(".sr-list"))
      total_results <- parsedDocument %>%
        toString() %>%
        str_match(., 'num_results":"(.*?)"') %>% 
        .[,2] %>%
        as.integer()
      pageNumber <- tryCatch(ceiling(total_results / results_per_page), error = function(e) {1})
      return(pageNumber)
    }
    getPageNumber("https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2F01%2F2010%20TO%2012%2F31%2F2010&fl_SiteID=5275&page=")
```

The  output I am getting is NA, when it should be numeric number

Comment: Works here, seemingly. Next time do `options(error=recover)` , which will let you debug in the environment where the error happens.

Comment: Okay thank you, I have one other question, do you know of any problems Rstudio has when running a webscraper?

Comment: I do not know, I'd be surprised if it interfered with what R does in its own right in that regard

Comment: Interesting only asking because I get no output when I run this function. What output were u able to get?

Comment: getPageNumber("https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2F01%2F2010%20TO%2012%2F31%2F2010&fl_SiteID=5275&page=")
 [1] 9

Comment: So for some reason I am getting NA when before I got the output you have. Would you know why that is?

Comment: Two possibilities really: total_results is NA or results_per_page is NA, but try the `browser()` thingy I put up in an answer below.

Comment: Also if you worry RStudio might be the source of your problems, try running your code in R without RStudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to troubleshoot your problems:

```r
getPageNumber <- function(URL) {
    parsedDocument <- read_html(URL)
    results_per_page <- length(parsedDocument %>% html_nodes(".sr-list"))
    total_results <- parsedDocument %>%
        toString() %>%
        str_match(., 'num_results":"(.*?)"') %>%
        .[,2] %>%
        as.integer()
    browser() ## <-- inject this here to stop when you get to this point.
    pageNumber <- tryCatch(ceiling(total_results / results_per_page), error = function(e) {1})
    return(pageNumber)
}

getPageNumber("https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2F01%2F2010%20TO%2012%2F31%2F2010&fl_SiteID=5275&page=")
```

This is what my R session looks like (I typed `total_results` and `results_per_page` there myself to see what they contained):

```
> getPageNumber("https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2F01%2F2010%20TO%2012%2F31%2F2010&fl_SiteID=5275&page=")
Called from: getPageNumber("https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2F01%2F2010%20TO%2012%2F31%2F2010&fl_SiteID=5275&page=")
Browse[1]> debug at #10: pageNumber <- tryCatch(ceiling(total_results/results_per_page), 
    error = function(e) {
        1
    })
Browse[2]> total_results
[1] 176
Browse[2]> results_per_page
[1] 20
Browse[2]> 
debug at #11: return(pageNumber)
Browse[2]> 
[1] 9
>
```

Other things you can do while you are inside the running function with browser():

1. put the html somewhere you can inspect it later: `cat( toString(parsedDocument), file="~/foo.html")`
2. look at: `parsedDocument %>% toString() %>% str_match('num_results":"(.*?)"')`

If you still experience NA as output, try changing your function code to this:

```r
getPageNumber <- function(URL) {
    parsedDocument <- read_html(URL)
    results_per_page <- length(parsedDocument %>% html_nodes(".sr-list"))
    total_results <- parsedDocument %>%
        toString() %>%
        str_match(., 'num_results":"(.*?)"') %>%
        .[,2] %>%
        as.integer()
    pageNumber <- tryCatch(ceiling(total_results / results_per_page), error = function(e) {1})
    if( is.na(pageNumber) ) {
       cat( "PAGENUMBER IS NA!\n" )
       cat( "total_results is:    ", total_results, "\n" )
       cat( "results_per_page is: ", results_per_page, "\n" )
       cat( toString(parsedDocument), file="~/foo.html")
       cat( "The HTML is stored here: ", normalizePath("~/foo.html") )
       cat( "Open it in a text editor and investigate why it went wrong\n" )
    }
    return(pageNumber)
}
```

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what browser did but it just fixed my entire program when trying it lol. Thank you!

Comment: Great! its a powerful tool, puts you up on the stage in the middle of the play. For completeness, 'You could instead have done `debug( getPageNumber )` , and then ran your function. You would then get to step through it from the beginning. Putting browser in there instead stops when it is at that point

Comment: Sadly i am once again getting my error where i get a NA for an output. After a lot of searching I believe it may be something on my end through my environment or package. It is odd because the program does run. Hope you may know of a solution. Best!